# Getting error when trying to set SQL Server Backup with Date Filename

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2012

I use the following script to make a normal backup:

```
USE SysproCompanyT
GO

EXEC('BACKUP DATABASE [Company] TO  DISK = N''G:\SQLBackups\INSTANCE1\MonthEndBackup\Company\MonthEndBackup.bak'' WITH NOFORMAT, COPY_ONLY,INIT,
        NAME = N''MonthEndBackup'', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
        ')
PRINT 'Backup of Syspro Company started'
GO
PRINT 'Backup of Syspro Company complete'
```

This works but I was trying to write a script which would give me a filename as a date and have tried the following:

```
DECLARE @TimeDate Varchar(256);

SET @TimeDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(Varchar(256),GETDATE(), 126), ':','');
DECLARE @location VARCHAR(200) = '\\AAVM-SQL01\SQLBackups$\INSTANCE1\MonthEndBackup\Company' + @TimeDate + '.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE [Company]
TO DISK = @location
WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME= Company, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10
```

Unfortunately I get no backup and if I add GO at the end of the statement I get an error

> SQL Server native client 10 : must declare the scalar variable when trying to create backup

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks.

Domdew

Answer (score 0):

The value for `DISK` must be a string literal. If you want to pass a dynamic value, you need to use dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @TimeDate Varchar(256),
        @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @TimeDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(Varchar(256),GETDATE(), 126), ':','');
DECLARE @location VARCHAR(200) = '\\AAVM-SQL01\SQLBackups$\INSTANCE1\MonthEndBackup\Company' + @TimeDate + '.bak'

SET @SQL = N'BACKUP DATABASE [Company]' + @CRLF +
           N'TO DISK = N''' + REPLACE(@location, '''','''''') + N'''' + @CRLF + --Replace is there incase the path ever changes, and it might have a single quote (') in it.
           N'WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, NAME= Company, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: This did not work. I am looking to keep the same path.

Comment: *"This did not work."* doesn't tell me much on why it didn't work.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'Company'.

Comment: @domdew that's due to `NAME= Company`, which is something you supplied in your original code.

Comment: Larnu I corrected everything now I get an Must Declare Scalar Variable Error for @SQL.

Comment: You took out the `DECLARE` @domdew ... I declare that in my statement.